# Out of sync SyncListStruct - Unity

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine

I have a struct which I use as a type on the SyncListStruct and then I inherit from SyncListStruct in allow me to have a list with the structs that can be synchronized from the client to the server. The problem I get is that the declaration of the subclass of the SyncListStruct give me the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: out of sync
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Enumerator[System.String,System.Int32].VerifyState
>   () (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:912)
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Enumerator[System.String,System.Int32].MoveNext
>   () (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:835)
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+KeyCollection+Enumerator[System.String,System.Int32].MoveNext
>   () (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:1028)
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkCRC.Dump
>   (UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkSystem.CRCMessageEntry[] remoteScripts)
>   (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Runtime/NetworkCRC.cs:106)
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkCRC.ValidateInternal
>   (UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkSystem.CRCMessageEntry[] remoteScripts,
>   Int32 numChannels) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Runtime/NetworkCRC.cs:75)
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkCRC.Validate
>   (UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkSystem.CRCMessageEntry[] scripts, Int32
>   numChannels) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Runtime/NetworkCRC.cs:66)
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkClient.OnCRC
>   (UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkMessage netMsg) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Runtime/NetworkClient.cs:801)
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkConnection.HandleReader
>   (UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkReader reader, Int32 receivedSize,
>   Int32 channelId) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Runtime/NetworkConnection.cs:430)
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkConnection.HandleBytes (System.Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 receivedSize, Int32 channelId) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Runtime/NetworkConnection.cs:386)
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkConnection.TransportRecieve
>   (System.Byte[] bytes, Int32 numBytes, Int32 channelId) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Runtime/NetworkConnection.cs:536)
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkClient.Update () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Runtime/NetworkClient.cs:648)
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkClient.UpdateClients () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Runtime/NetworkClient.cs:861)
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkIdentity.UNetStaticUpdate () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/Networking/Runtime/NetworkIdentity.cs:1055)

**My code:**

```
    public class TestClass: NetworkBehaviour
    { 
        public struct PlayerShootingStats
        {
            public string name;
            public int totalShots;
            public int onTargetShots;
        }

        public class SyncListPlayerShootingStats : SyncListStruct<PlayerShootingStats>{}

        private SyncListPlayerShootingStats playersShootingStats; // if I comment out this line I do not get an error

        void Awake()
        {
            playersShootingStats = new SyncListPlayerShootingStats();
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What Unity version are you using? What happens if you remove other scripts and attach only the script above? Do you still get the error?

Comment: Hi. I am using Unity 5.3.2f1. This is the only script attached to the game object on the scene. Then on another script I am finding the game object using `GameObject.FindObject()` and calling some method that will actually increment the int's on the struct. At the moment I have commented out everything to try and pinpoint the error. The error still exists on the code above. I have not found any solutions yet.

Comment: There about 10 bug reports on this and your code runs fine on my machine.  I am using 5.4 beta and I guess it is fixed on that version since I am not getting any error. Download 5.4beta http://unity3d.com/unity/beta